# Calculated column using 4 different columns to derive an "approve" or "Decline" answer

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list, if-statement

I would like to use an IF function to obtain an answer to "Approve" or "Decline" within a SharePoint list. My formula works in Excel but not in SharePoint.

I have 4 SharePoint columns:

column name = [Request Type], excel cell =G2  (to be "approved" the word "TD" must be chosen)

column name = [Position title], excel cell =F2 (to be "approved" the word "MEM" must be chosen)

column name = [% Discount], excel cell =J2  (to be "approved" value must be <=0.6)

column name = [Criteria Total], excel cell =S2 (to be "approved" value must be >=100)

My formula works in Excel but not in SharePoint.
Excel formula is: `=IF(AND(G2="TD",F2="MEM",S2>=100,J2<0.7),"APPROVE","DECLINE")`

When I enter it in SharePoint I change the cells to the column name and it always says "decline" when the answer should be "approve"

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the data type of `[% Discount]` and `[Criteria Total]` columns in SharePoint list?

Comment: [% Discount] = choice of values ranging from 0.1 through to 2.0 (increments of 0.1)
[Criteria Total] = calculated column (=sum) adding up 3 column values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `[Criteria Total]` has returned data type as **Number**, you can use below formula:

```
=IF(AND([Request Type] = "TD", [Position title] = "MEM", [Criteria Total] >= 100, Value([% Discount]) <= 0.6), "APPROVE", "DECLINE")
```

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [AND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-78956048-53c7-484a-ab0b-6e70d7f03400)
2. [VALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-1fc46e51-4a25-4ba0-bce2-512dd5d4d872)

Comment: Ganesh, you are wonderful.. it works... thank you so very much.. Have a wonderful rest of the week :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND([Request Type]="TD",[Position title]="MEM",[Criteria Total]>=100,[% Discount]<0.7),"APPROVE","DECLINE")
```

Test result:
[image]
[image]
**Updated:**

```
=IF(AND([Request Type]="TD",[Position title]="MEM",[Criteria Total]>=100,VALUE([% Discount])<0.7),"APPROVE","DECLINE")
```

[image]
[image]
Because the original value of `% Discount` is a text value, it needs to be converted to a number.
[VALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-1fc46e51-4a25-4ba0-bce2-512dd5d4d872)

Comment: it has not worked - wondering if thats because % discount is a choice field starting at 0.1 (increments of 0.1) all the way to 2.0.
Also Criteria Total is also a calculated total (=sum) adding up 3 columns